# Why is my component, which is outside of the foreach loop, being looped through?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, while-loop

Why is my component, which is outside of the foreach loop, being looped through?  I have a foreach loop that is getting all posts of a certain category.  The loop is displaying all of my posts of that category correctly.

The problem I am having is that a component (which has its own while loop - ACF repeater) is showing component content for the last child post that is displayed.

**Example:**

*Structure*

- Case Studies w/ Panel Component content of 0 (Parent)

  - Case Study 1 - w/ Panel Component content of 1 (Child)
  - Case Study 2 - w/ Panel Component content of 2 (Child)
  - Case Study 3 - w/ Panel Component content of 3 (Child)

The content value "3" will be displayed on the Case Studies (Parent) page instead of a value of "0".

I've been trying to tackle this all day and I can't figure out what is going on.  Any help is much appreciated.

**Panel Component:**

```
<!-- Panels Component: w/ ACF repeater loop -->

<section class="two-col-grid-panel">
<?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('panels') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('panels') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <div class="panel">
                <h2><?php the_sub_field('panel_heading'); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('panel_description'); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_sub_field('button_link'); ?>" class="small-card__btn"><?php the_sub_field('button_text'); ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif;
?>
</section>
```

**Custom Template (Parent): w/ foreach loop**

```
<main>
    <section id="hero-container" class="single-col-card-container">
        <div class="small-card-container">
            <div class="studies-grid-container">
                <?php
                $args  = array(
                    'cat' => 6,
                    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
                    'order'           => 'ASC'
                ); 
                $posts = get_posts($args);
                foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
                    <div class="grid__item">
                        <div class="card">
                            <!-- Retrieve the image and alt text in repeater -->
                            <img class="small-card__img" src="http://localhost/master/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/product-design.jpg" alt="Product Design">
                            <div class="small-card__content">
                                <h2 class="small-card__header"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                <p class="small-card__text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="small-card__btn">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </section>

    <?php get_template_part('component', 'panels'); ?>
</main>
```

**Custom Child Template**

```
<main>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <section class="browser-hero-container">
            <div class="browser-hero">
                <?php 
                    $imageID = get_field('browser_hero_image');
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'full' );
                    $alt = get_post_meta($imageID , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('browser_hero_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="three-col-grid-block-container">
            <?php
                // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                if( have_rows('case_study_tiles') ):
                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows('case_study_tiles') ) : the_row(); ?>
                        <div class="grid-block-item">
                            <h3><?php the_sub_field('tile_title'); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php the_sub_field('tile_description'); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
        </section>

        <?php get_template_part('component', 'panels'); ?>

        <?php //if ( ! post_password_required() ) comments_template( '', true ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</main>
```

**var_dump**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[2099]
      public 'ID' => int 347
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2020-04-19 15:35:05' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 15:35:05' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string '<!-- wp:paragraph -->
        <p>Look up at the night sky, and find yourself immersed in the amazing mountain range of Aspen.</p>
        <!-- /wp:paragraph -->' (length=144)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Case Study 1' (length=12)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'case-study-1' (length=12)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2020-04-19 16:12:33' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 16:12:33' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/master/?p=347' (length=30)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(WP_Post)[1742]
      public 'ID' => int 352
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2020-04-19 16:13:31' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 16:13:31' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string '<!-- wp:paragraph -->
        <p>Look up at the night sky, and find yourself immersed in the amazing mountain range of Aspen.2</p>
        <!-- /wp:paragraph -->' (length=145)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Case Study 2' (length=12)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'case-study-2' (length=12)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2020-04-19 16:53:19' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 16:53:19' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/master/?p=352' (length=30)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(WP_Post)[2097]
      public 'ID' => int 356
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2020-04-19 16:46:24' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 16:46:24' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string '<!-- wp:paragraph -->
        <p>Look up at the night sky, and find yourself immersed in the amazing mountain range of Aspen.3</p>
        <!-- /wp:paragraph -->' (length=145)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Case Study 3' (length=12)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'case-study-3' (length=12)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2020-04-24 03:14:02' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-04-24 03:14:02' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/master/?p=356' (length=30)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  3 => 
    object(WP_Post)[2096]
      public 'ID' => int 359
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2020-04-19 16:47:09' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 16:47:09' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string '<!-- wp:paragraph -->
        <p>Look up at the night sky, and find yourself immersed in the amazing mountain range of Aspen.4</p>
        <!-- /wp:paragraph -->' (length=145)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Case Study 4' (length=12)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'case-study-4' (length=12)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2020-04-19 16:53:09' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 16:53:09' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/master/?p=359' (length=30)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  4 => 
    object(WP_Post)[1938]
      public 'ID' => int 364
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2020-04-19 20:15:07' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-04-19 20:15:07' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string '<!-- wp:paragraph -->
        <p>Look up at the night sky, and find yourself immersed in the amazing mountain range of Aspen.5</p>
        <!-- /wp:paragraph -->' (length=145)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Case Study 5' (length=12)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'case-study-5' (length=12)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2020-04-27 13:33:56' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-04-27 13:33:56' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/master/?p=364' (length=30)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any fields named the same that may be causing scoping issues?

Comment: @JoelHager thanks for the reply.  The only fields that are named the same are in the "Panel Component".  Panel Component is being used inside of Custom Template and Custom Child Template.  The LOOP appears to be picking up the values for the Panel Component inside of the Custom Child Component and displaying them on the Custom Template.  Hopefully that's a bit clearer.

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump $posts in your template? Just see what it's grabbing?

Comment: @JoelHager I've added the var_dump records in the original question.  Please see above. (For the record the following text is displaying from where my component is being displayed - "Look up at the night sky, and find yourself immersed in the amazing mountain range of Aspen.5").

Comment: @JoelHager I appreciate your earlier comments.  Do you have any other thoughts from the var_dump I posted?

Comment: Sorry about that. Forgot about this. The var dump seems fine (the posts). This is very curious.

Comment: Are the panels *in* the posts? Like acf panels for each post?

Comment: What query is your child template using to access the posts?

Comment: @JoelHager yes, the panels are in a single component (panels.php) and they are being used in the post template (child) as well as the parent template.  I'm using the `get_posts()` to get the posts on my parent.  There is no query being used on the child template, only advanced custom fields (ACF).

Comment: Have_posts() is always part of a query. So where are you getting the query for child template? Seems like it's just getting a global query by default. What's the relationship between parent and child?

Comment: @JoelHager the code I provided above for the child is all in its entirety.  As I said before, there is no query, just advanced custom fields.  The relationship between the parent and child is one where the parent pulls in all posts (children) of a category (cat => case study).  Again, the child is just a "post" template that has ACF fields.  Hopefully that's more clear?

Comment: I understand what you're saying on that. However, I'm telling you that `have_posts()` is always using a WP_Query object, so if you're not specifying *which* query to use, it'll use the global query. vardump `have_posts()` in your child template and see what it's pulling from.